# Difference between jQuery .data() and setAttribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

1) When setting **user data** (see [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u3c1vfk9/))  with :

```
  document.getElementById('myelement1').setAttribute('data-size', 20);
```

I can see this when analyzing the element with the browser's inspector :

```
<div id="myelement1" data-size="20">Blah</div>
```

---

2) When setting user data with jQuery :

```
$('#myelement2').data('size', 20);
```

I can see this when analyzing the element with the browser's inspector :

```
<div id="myelement2">Blah</div>
```

---

**Why is the element present in the DOM in 1) but not in 2) ?**

**How does jQuery `.data('size', 20)` store the data, and where if it's not in the DOM ?**
(I'm not advanced enough in JS to find the exact place in the code that does that)

Comment: `data()` stores in an internal object, `$.cache`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery doesn't attach a physical attribute to the element. It keeps an internal object (called `cache`) where it keeps the data, with a reference to the element that it corresponds to - it isn't stored in the DOM or an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The data for the elements are stored internally, i.e. in a collection local to the jQuery code.

From the documentation of the [`data` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/'):

> "The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property
>   is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data
>   values are then stored internally in jQuery)."

Note that although the `data` method doesn't change the data attribute, setting a data attribute will put it in the DOM and also make it available using the `data` method:

```
$('#myelement2').attr('data-size', 20);

console.log($('#myelement2').data('size')); // shows 20
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kq93n878/